# Database error: Invalid SQL: WHERE id IN (91220,91222,91232,91233,91244,91263,

Tags: php, mysql, database, backend

The SQL below when echoed in the PHP script displays only `WHERE id IN (91220,91222,91232,91233,91244,91263,91264,91277)`

Please help me find what is wrong with the SQL.

```
$sql = "UPDATE customers SET customers.name=AES_ENCRYPT('" . self::PII_OBFUSCATE_NAME . "','" . AES_CRYPT_KEY . "')"
    . ", address1=AES_ENCRYPT('" . self::PII_OBFUSCATE_ADDRESS1 . "','" . AES_CRYPT_KEY . "')"
    . ", day_phone=AES_ENCRYPT('" . self::PII_OBFUSCATE_PHONE . "','" . AES_CRYPT_KEY . "')"
    . ", nite_phone=AES_ENCRYPT('" . self::PII_OBFUSCATE_PHONE . "','" . AES_CRYPT_KEY . "')"
    . (is_array($customers_to_obfuscate))
        ? " WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $customers_to_obfuscate) . ")"
        : " WHERE id = '$customers_to_obfuscate'";
```

Comment: You need to set your braces properly. You are currently applying the ternary operator to _everything_ that comes before it.

Comment: Could you please help me fix it by correcting the ternary operator?

Comment: I thought I just _did_ that.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by adding one more pair of braces around the ternary operator as `((is_array($orders_to_obfuscate))
    ? " WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $orders_to_obfuscate) . ")"
    : " WHERE id = '$orders_to_obfuscate'");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your braces in the ternary operator. It must look like follows:

```
((is_array($orders_to_obfuscate)) ? " WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $orders_to_obfuscate) . ")" : " WHERE id = '$orders_to_obfuscate'");
```